# rspec - how to compare to an actual DateTime in the expect?

Tags: ruby, rspec

My rspec:

```
it "can show the current month name" do
  expect(Calendar.create_date_using_month(1)).to eq '2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500'
end
```

fails with:

```
expected: "2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500"
     got: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500
```

For my code:

```
def self.create_date_using_month(n)
  Time.new(2000,n,1)
end
```

Should/can I change the RSpec so that I am comparing to an actual string not a date?

I tried: `Date.strptime("{ 2000, 1, 1 }", "{ %Y, %m, %d }")`

but that gives me

```
   expected: #<Date: 2000-01-01 ((2451545j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
        got: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about what exactly you're testing here.  If `create_data_using_month` creates a `Time` object, you should compare it with a `Time` object.

This message:

```
expected: "2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500"
     got: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500
```

is telling you it expected the literal string with the date, but got an object whose to_s happens to be the same.

So I guess you could "fix" it, by changing this:

```
it "can show the current month name" do
  expect(Calendar.create_date_using_month(1).to_s).to eq '2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500'
end
```

But that seems odd, is that what you want?  You'll also likely have issues if you test on a machine with different time zone settings.

I'd just do this:

```
it "can show the current month name" do
  expect(Calendar.create_date_using_month(1)).to eq Time.new(2000, 1, 1)
end
```

which passes for me just fine.

Comment: Yes the last option was what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're having a microseconds issue.

You should use to_i conversion of the date to avoid dealing with microseconds issue (if not relevant).

```
Time.now().to_i.should == Time.now().to_i
```

and I do think this work too

```
Time.now().should.eql?(Time.now())
```

I've also write a custom matcher:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_equal_to_time do |another_date|
  match do |a_date|
    a_date.to_i.should == another_date.to_i
  end
end
```

which can be use like this

```
Time.now().should be_equal_to_time(Time.now())
```

Answer (score 2):

DateTime Class http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html

```
DateTime.parse('2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0500') == DateTime.new(2000,1,1,0,0,0,'-5')
#=> true
```

You should always try and compare the object and not the it's string value unless you are specifically testing its ability to return a specific string. This is because to_s is simply am method and not a true representation of the object.